# Chart js axes border

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i'm trying to implement a chart with chartJs and i want to remove all the borders of it, but there is still one that is visible.
[Here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyoea.png)

These are the options that i used:

```
const options = {
    type: 'line',
    radius: 5,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false,
                showBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
                color: '#2D4059',
                font: {
                    size: 14,
                    family: 'Lexend-SemiBold'
                }
            }
        },
        y: {
            grid: {
                display: false,
                showBorder: false,
            },
            ticks: {
                display: false,
                stepSize: 53
            },
            min: 0,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'top',
            color: '#2D4059',
                font: {
                    size: 14,
                    family: 'Lexend-SemiBold'
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me figuring this out? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you want to hide is the Y axis itself.
To do so, replace the code inside options.scales.y by this

```
y:{
  display:false
},
```

[Here's a code pen](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/NWEojXg) to see the result